# How to explain why a low-momentum electron can pass through atomic lattice like a free particle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering

It is argued that when an electron wave with long wavelength (much longer than the separation between metal atoms) is incident on a thing sheet of metal, it pass through as if it is a free particle.

How can I understand intuitively why this is the case? Apparently, I just need to understand why the reflected waves are cancelled out. But how could this happen? Apparently, the wave reflected at each atom is slightly out of phase, so intuitively they could cancel out, but how can I make sure that it ends up in complete cancellation? (I tried a little bit of integration to calculate the resultant intensity at an arbitrary point in space, but the integrand includes euclidean distance $\sqrt {x^2 +y^2}$ **inside** $\sin$ and $\cos$, which makes it nearly an impossible job). Of course I can show that it cancels out on the lattice, but what about the situation out of the lattice?

Comment: My intuition is that when an electron reflects off of a thin sheet of metal, the magnitude of momentum transfer must be greater than zero and less than twice the momentum of the incident electron. Moreover, allowed values of momentum transfers are given by the lattice spacings of the atoms, and if the spacings are very small compared to the electron wavelength, there is no allowed nonzero momentum transfer between the electron and the lattice.

Comment: can you give a link that shows the phenomenon? I would consider electron tunneling, but it needs a clear context as the question is not clear